# C++ Beginning Program

Tags: c++

Write a program using c++ that asks the user for a integer number of cents and outputs how many of each type of coin would represent that amount with the fewest total number of coins. No loops please.

Example output
Enter cents:
48
Change:
Q:1
D:2
N:0
P:3

Comment: Hello - you say "no loops" -EDITED (I should think thoroughly before posting) - it's possible - but you'll need mods (%) and divs (int (/)) - try it out, let me know if you need the code

Comment: Yes, it has to be done with no loops.

Comment: i didn't understand what is your problem

Comment: I had a feeling it would need mods and divs (int). I also maybe thinking constants?

Comment: If you dont know how to do it on paper then stop coding and first find out what you want to code

Comment: ...what I wanted to say is: This question is not really about coding, maybe maths

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function, and a couple of lines... that might help point you in the direction you want

```
int iQ = coincount( c, 25);
c = c - (iQ * 25);

----
int coincount( int iTotal, int iCoin )
{
    return ( (int) iTotal / iCoin );
}
```

Comment: integer division is implemented using a loop, tut tut.

Comment: @Corey - true, but his preclusion seems to be for C++ loops (while/for), not internal asm

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments mentioned, this can be solved using a sequence of divisions and mods. The divisions will tell you how many coins of a type you have, and the mods will tell you how much change you have left to distribute to the smaller denominations.

For starters, you will want to declare some `int`s to store the coin amounts. Styles vary, but something like `int NumQuarters`, `int NumDimes`, etc, should suffice. Declare those just after you take the user input.

Then the coin counts are simply `c` divided by the value of a given coin, starting with the largest denomination:

`NumQuarters = c / Q;`

To ensure that you only distribute what's left to the smaller denominations, mod your user's input by that same coin value and store that back into `c`:

`c = c % Q;`

Repeat that same process for all the denominations and you will have your coin counts. Then just insert them into your `cout`'s and you should be done:

`cout << "Q: " << NumQuarters << "\n";`